# Rails Route "as"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code snippet it has 3 types of "as"
Can anybody explain about 3 different "as"

1. as: 'drivers_confirmation'
2. :as -> 'user_registration'
3. as :user do

   ```
   get 'drivers/confirmation' => "root#index", as: 'drivers_confirmation'

   namespace :api do
   get 'describe/models'
   get 'status' => 'status#index'

       as :user do
         put 'v1/users' => 'v1/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
       #   post "login" => "v1/sessions#create"
       #   get "currentUser" => "v1/sessions#current"
       end

       as :driver do
         get "v1/drivers/session" => "v1/drivers/sessions#current"
       end
   ```

   end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as: 'drivers_confirmation'` and `:as => 'user_registration'` are the same.

It's the old and new ruby hash syntax. They are there to be able to use url helpers in your views (`drivers_confirmation_path` and `user_registration_path`)

`as :user do` is probably from Devise, those routes are scoped to specific kinds of users.

Comment: I was searching about devise_for but couldn't find proper explanation, can you give me tip please?

Answer (score 0):

Those methods expect a hash to be passed to it in that context.  What you're describing are three ways to write a Ruby hash.

The form `as: 'drivers_confirmation'` is [the "newer"](http://breakthebit.org/post/8453341914/ruby-19-and-the-new-hash-syntax) and more preferred (from what I've seen) approach to creating hashes, so long as the key you're using can be directly converted to a symbol.

The form `:as => 'user_registration'` is the older style of writing a hash.

The form `as :user` is a method which is likely expecting a symbol to be passed to it as opposed to it being any form of hash.